# can't sort multiple jq grids

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

i'm having 3 grids in my html page i use

> loadonce: true;
>   datatype: xml;

after data has been loaded i change the

> datatype: local;

i do this so that when i do sorting or paging, i dont want to call a reload.
This works well when i have only one grid in my page but when i have 3 grids on my page , the sorting is not working.

Can anyone please help.

```
this.createPortServerGrid = function(){
    //_this.rowDataLoaded = false;
    _this.X$("#serverGrid").jqGrid({
        mtype : 'POST',
        url : DXOP_SERVER,
        datatype : "xml",
        postData : {
            swNote1 : '<epiq> <request> <action> <object>commline</object> <method>find</method> <language>enus</language> </action> <data> <row> <dynamic>0</dynamic> </row> </data> <sql> <orderby>devicename</orderby> </sql> </request> </epiq>'
        },
        colModel : [ {
            label : "Name",
            name : 'name',
            index : 'name',
            xmlmap : "name"
        }, {
            label : "Port",
            name : 'devicename',
            index : 'devicename',
            sorttype: 'int',
            xmlmap : "devicename"
        }, {
            label : "Port State",
            name : 'state',
            index : 'state',
            xmlmap : "state"

        }, {
            name : 'pk',
            index : 'pk',
            xmlmap : "pk",
            hidden : true
        }, {
            name : 'childserverfk',
            index : 'childserverfk',
            xmlmap : "childserverfk",
            hidden : true
        },

        {
            name : 'porttmplfk',
            index : 'porttmplfk',
            xmlmap : "porttmplfk",
            hidden : true
        } ],

        xmlReader : {
            root : "data",
            row : "row",
            repeatitems : false,
            id : "pk"
        },

        rowNum : 10,
        height : 400,
        autowidth : true,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        pager : '#pager3',
        altRows : true,
        sortname : 'name',
        loadonce : true,
        recordpos : 'left',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        multiselect : false,
        afterInsertRow : function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
            $('#' + rowid).contextMenu('port_portMenuJqGrid',
_this.serverPortMenu);
        },
        loadComplete : function(rowId) {
            var sraw = _this.X$("#serverGrid").getGridParam('xmlRawData');
            handleErrorMessage(sraw);
            _this.serverParseRowData(sraw);
            _this.createPortTemplateGrid();

            _this.serverfilterGrid();
            if(_this.serPortSel != null){                                   
                _this.X$('#serverGrid').jqGrid('setSelection',
_this.serPortSel); 
            }
            _this.X$('#serverGrid').setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
            alert("********"+_this.X$('#serverGrid').setGridParam('datatype')[0]);
        },
        onSelectRow : _this.loadServerGrid,
        ondblClickRow : _this.editServerTemplate

    });
};
this.createCurrentSessionGrid = function(){
    _this.X$("#currentTemplGrid").jqGrid({
        mtype : 'POST',
        url : DXOP_SERVER,
        datatype : "xml",
        postData : {
            swNote1 : '<epiq> <request> <action> <object>commline</object> <method>find</method> <language>enus</language> </action> <data> <row> <dynamic>1</dynamic> </row> </data> <sql> <orderby>devicename</orderby> </sql> </request> </epiq>'
        },
        colModel : [ {
            label : " Current File Name",
            name : 'currentfilename',
            index : 'currentfilename',
            xmlmap : "currentfilename"
        }, {
            label : "Current Byte Sent",
            name : 'currentbytessent',
            index : 'currentbytessent',
            xmlmap : "currentbytessent"
        }, {
            label : "Current Byte Recived",
            name : 'currentbytesreceived',
            index : 'currentbytesreceived',
            xmlmap : "currentbytesreceived"
        }, {
            label : "Port State",
            name : 'state',
            index : 'state',
            xmlmap : "state"

        }, {
            label : "Current Endpoint",
            name : 'currentendpoint',
            index : 'currentendpoint',
            xmlmap : "currentendpoint"

        }, {
            label : "Current User",
            name : 'dynamic',
            index : 'dynamic',
            xmlmap : "dynamic"

        }, {
            name : 'pk',
            index : 'pk',
            xmlmap : "pk",
            hidden : true
        } ],

        xmlReader : {
            root : "data",
            row : "row",
            repeatitems : false,
            id : "pk"
        },

        rowNum : 10,
        height : 400,
        autowidth : true,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        pager : '#pager3',
        altRows : true,
        //loadonce : true,
        sortname : 'id',
        recordpos : 'left',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        multiselect : false,
        afterInsertRow : function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
            $('#' + rowid).contextMenu('port_currentMenuJqGrid',
_this.currentSessionMenu);
        }
        ,onSelectRow : _this.curSessionSelectedRow,
        loadComplete : function(rowId) {
            var craw = _this.X$("#currentTemplGrid") .getGridParam('xmlRawData');
            handleErrorMessage(craw);
            _this.currentParseRowData(craw);
            _this.currentfilterGrid();
            if(_this.curSessnSel != null){
                _this.X$('#currentTemplGrid').jqGrid('setSelection',
_this.curSessnSel); 
            }
        }

    });
};
this.curSessionSelectedRow = function(){
    _this.portTempSel = _this.X$("#currentTemplGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
};
this.createPortTemplateGrid = function(){
    _this.X$("#portTemplGrid").jqGrid({
        mtype : 'POST',
        url : DXOP_SERVER,
        datatype : "xml",
        postData : getPostData('<action> <object>porttemplate</object> <method>find</method> <language>enus</language> </action> <data> <row/> </data> '),
        colModel : [ {
            label : "Name",
            name : 'name',
            index : 'name',
            xmlmap : "name"
        }, {
            label : "Type",
            name : 'linetype',
            index : 'linetype',
            xmlmap : "linetype"

        }, {
            label : "Job Look up Timeout",
            name : 'getworktimeout',
            index : 'getworktimeout',
            xmlmap : "getworktimeout"

        }, {
            name : 'pk',
            index : 'pk',
            xmlmap : "pk",
            hidden : true
        } ],

        xmlReader : {
            root : "data",
            row : "row",
            repeatitems : false,
            id : "pk"
        },

        rowNum : 10,
        height : 400,
        autowidth : true,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        pager : '#pager2',
        loadonce : true,
        altRows : true,
        sortname : 'name',
        recordpos : 'left',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        multiselect : false,
        afterInsertRow : function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
            $('#' + rowid).contextMenu('port_porttemplMenuJqGrid',
_this.portTemplateMenu);
        },
        onSelectRow : _this.portTemplSelectedRow,
        ondblClickRow : _this.editPortTemplate,
        loadComplete : function(rowId) {
            var traw = _this.X$("#portTemplGrid").getGridParam('xmlRawData');
            handleErrorMessage(traw);                       
            _this.templateParseRowData(traw);
            _this.createCurrentSessionGrid();
            //_this.X$("#portTemplGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
            //_this.X$("#portTemplGrid").setGridParam({datatype:'xml'}).trigger('reloadGrid');

            _this.X$('#portTemplGrid').setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
            _this.portfilterGrid();
            if(_this.portTempSel != null){
                _this.X$('#portTemplGrid').jqGrid('setSelection',
_this.portTempSel); 
            }
        }
    });
};
```

thanks,

Devan

Comment: You should post the JavaScript code which you use. If you use `loadonce: true` the datatype will be changed to `'local'` automatically by jqGrid after the first data loading from the server. It is important, that you post the XML data which you use for all grids. Typical problem with many grids on one page - id duplicates.

Comment: if you post include the code you should select it and click "{}" button which add 4 blanks at the beginning of every line. Moreover you should include test XML data for the grids. Without the data one can't test the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You use for the grids "#serverGrid" and "#currentTemplGrid" the same pager '#pager3' which is not permitted. You can't share one pager div between the grids.

Moreover if some grid columns should be interpret not as text you should define `sorttype` which described the data type.

If you use `afterInsertRow` the grid will work much slowly. If you need to make data binding to all rows inside of `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    // your old code here and then
    $('tr.jqgrow',this).contextMenu('port_portMenuJqGrid',_this.serverPortMenu);
}
```

After removing of `afterInsertRow` you should add `gridview:true` parameter to the grid. It will improve the grid performance in many times.